# What .NET instrumenting framework would you recommend and why?

Tags: logging, log4net, instrumentation

I only have experience with [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) however that does not mean that there are not better fish in the sea.  I don't have time to go fishing but I do I have 60 seconds to post to SO.

So what all has everyone used and their experiences with it?

- I understand this is subjective, but please provide concrete reasons of why **you** have your opinion (Such as Acme Logging worked very well in that configuration, or it didn't support remote monitoring which we needed, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend taking a look at [ELMAH](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersForASPNETAndMVCToo.aspx)

**EDIT :** I forgot my opinion: SO uses it :)

Comment: Thank you, I was just about ready to comment and ask you why :)